# c# calculation help (TExtractor callid)

Tags: c#, math

I'm pretty useless when it comes to math and I have a problem I need help with.
This has nothing to do with schoolwork, it's in fact about alcatel and the ticketextractor. I have two values that needs to be calculated in a c# application according to a formula specified in their documentation:

"The global callid is equal to: callid1 multiplied by 2 power 32 plus callid2"

As I said I'm not big with maths so that statement says nothing to me. If anyone know how to calculate it i'd appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: The statement says gcallid = (callid1 *(2^32)) + callid2.
However, using this exact code will run into problems on most computers due to overflows. So, use shift operators combined with big variables like long or long long to calculate this value. See David's post for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is you'll need a 64 bit value to store it in. Assuming your callId values are (32 bit) ints, you'd need to do something like this.

```
int callId1, callId2;
...
long globalCallId = ((long)callId1 << 32) + callId2;
```

`<<` is the bit shift operator - shifting 32 bits is the equivalent of multiplying by 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to shift callid1 by 32 bits.

```
long globalCallId = ((long)callid1 << 32) + callid2;
```

Comment: Please note that this will only work if both callid1 and callid2 are longs. Explicit casting to long is required if they are ints. You have to be careful of overflows while using shift operations.

Comment: @apoorv020: It's about the calculation here, not about the types. Who said that they aren't long? If you prefer, I'll cast it.

Answer (score 0):

So global callid = callid1 * 2<sup>32</sup> + callid2. You can use:

```
long globalCallID = (callid1 << 32) + callid2
```

This uses the fact that `a << b == a multiplied by 2 to the power of b`.

Comment: Please note that this will only work if both callid1 and callid2 are longs. Explicit casting to long is required if they are ints. You have to be careful of overflows while using shift operations.

Comment: @apoorv020: Please stop downvoting all the answers which miss the cast. You don't know if it is actually needed.

Comment: Maybe I overdid it a bit. I apologize.